# A line in the lstlisting environment cannot start with "\end{frame}" in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, listings

I'm making a presentation about LaTeX using the beamer package (v3.10). I'm using the listings (v1.4) package to print pieces of latex source code and highlight the keywords.

It seems that the following minimal example can't compile :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]tex}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Using latexmk with the latexila editor, I got this error :

```
Missing } inserted
```

Whereas, using pdftex with the latexila editor, I got a more verbose output :

```
\begin{lstlisting} on input line 1 ended by \end{beamer@framepauses}.
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup
\begin{lstlisting} on input line 1 ended by \end{beamer@frameslide}.
Undefined control sequence
Package Listings Error: Extra \endlstlisting
\begin{beamer@framepauses} on input line 17 ended by \end{lstlisting}.
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup
\begin{beamer@framepauses} on input line 17 ended by \end{document}.
You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode
\begin{beamer@framepauses} on input line 17 ended by \end{document}.
```

After some research, It seems that even with the `[fragile]` option passed on to `\frame`, there is a problem with the last line of the quoted code : `\end{frame}`.

One workaround is to indent from at least one space this line :

```
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
 \end{frame}
\end{lstlisting}
```

My conclusion is : a line in the `lstlisting` environment cannot start with `\end{frame}`.
Did I do something wrong ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) does a lot of leg work when setting the `frame` environment, since it might have to parse the contents more than once in order to take seemingly single *slides* and break them into number of *frames*. As a safe bet, you can box the contents of your listing outside the frame and then include the pre-typeset box:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]tex}
\newsavebox{\codebox}% For storing listings

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\codebox}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}
\usebox{\codebox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}​
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know all these "box" commands ! Indeed, it works but I face some issues since I use listings inside `itemize` environment : my savebox inserted is too wide.It seems that there is no option to set width using the `lrbox` environment. I tried with the `savebox` command, but I didn't succeed... Any idea ?

Comment: I answer my own question, I can change manually the line width inside `lrbox` environment. For example : `\setlength{\linewidth}{0.9\linewidth}`

Comment: @RémiG.: Here it is better to specify the width as an optional argument to `lstlisting`'s `linewidth` key-value. That is, use something like `\begin{lstlisting}[linewidth=.9\textwidth]`.

Answer (score 6):

If you use the "containsverbatim" option instead of "fragile" your minimal example works:

```
\begin{frame}[containsverbatim]{test}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
```

I found the solution in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981008/latex-issue-with-beamer-and-listings