# Beamer and listings... how to include \end{frame} multiple times

Tags: beamer, listings, boxes

Following up on [THIS QUESTION](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73366/a-line-in-the-lstlisting-environment-cannot-start-with-endframe-in-a-beamer), I want to include code in my slides. The code includes "\end{frame}", so I had to box the code as suggested in the link, but if I want to include code including "\end{frame}" multiple times, I'm hopeless...

In the MWE below, I would like to include the code with "First slide" in the first slide, and the code with "Second slide" in the second slide... Any help?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset
{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\tt\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
}

\newsavebox{\codebox}% For storing listings

\title{A Tiny Example}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\codebox}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{frame}
First slide
\end{frame}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{lrbox}{\codebox}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{frame}
Second slide
\end{frame}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{First Slide}
\usebox{\codebox}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Second Slide}
\usebox{\codebox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply move the box second definition behind the first slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset
{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\tt\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
}

\newsavebox{\codebox}% For storing listings

\title{A Tiny Example}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\codebox}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{frame}
First slide
\end{frame}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}


\maketitle

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{First Slide}
\usebox{\codebox}
\end{frame}

\begin{lrbox}{\codebox}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{frame}
Second slide
\end{frame}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Second Slide}
\usebox{\codebox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```